# Entity-framework анонимные объекты

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Есть 2 модельки. Команда и тренер.

Команда:

```
public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Coach> Coachs { get; set; }

        public Team()
        {
            Coachs = new List<Coach>();
        }
```

Тренер:

```
public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int? TeamId { get; set; }
        public virtual Team Team { get; set; }
```

Как вы видите, реализована связь один ко многим. И например я хочу сделать себе для дальнейшего использования набор данных, например для того же что бы потом зсунуть его в dataGridView. Набор состоит из названия команды и имени тренера команды. Оба эти свойства называются Name. Вытащить я их пытаюсь с помощью анонимных объектов:

```
Context db = new Context();
var table = db.Coachs.Select(c => new { c.Name, c.Team.Name });
```

Но при этом появляется ошибка:

> An anonymous type cannot have multiple properties with the same name.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как так сделать что бы с помощью анонимных объектов можно было выбрать 2 свойства с одинаковыми называниями? Или так нельзя сделать и нужно обязательно делать разные названия у свойств? Просто это нужно для того что бы сделать нужную модель данных для использование в dataGridView. Подготавливать DataTable как мне кажется дольше и муторнее. Такой способ по моему самый быстрый.

Comment: В чем проблема дать разные имена? А вообще сделали бы специальный класс для отображения и использовали бы его `db.Coachs.Select(c => new TeamDisplay(c));` навесив на его свойства атрибут `DisplayName`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`An anonymous type cannot have multiple properties with the same name.` - то есть надо делать свойства с разными названиями. Вы и в простом классе не сможете сделать 2 свойства с одинаковым названием, в анонимном и подавно.

Как пример

```
var table = db.Coachs.Select(c => new { Name = c.Name, TeamName = c.Team.Name });
```

Comment: tym, большое спасибо, хороший вариант. Не разу не видел такой конструкции, что бы при сборе анонимных объектов можно было им давать свои имена, не подскажите пожалуйста где про эту конструкцию почитать можно?

Comment: И сразу ещё такой вот вопрос, допустим я собрал анонимный класс и мне он нужен для того что бы поместить в dataGridView.datasource(приложение winforms). Но названия столбцов будут на английском, а мне нужно им дать русские названия. Как быть в таком случае? Как мне назвать по русски мои поля? Заранее в dataGridVIew подготовить столбцы с верными названиями? Или можно как то подругому? Просто в таком случае наверное мне всё же будет удобнее использовать подготовленный datatable чем использовать анонимные типы.

Comment: @Андрей анонимные типы - часть языка c#, соответственно почитать о них можно в [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb397696(v=vs.120).aspx)

Comment: @Андрей как вам лучше реализовать я не знаю, это зависит от ваших требований / архитектуры и прочих факторов. Из моего личного опыта, если вы собираетесь показывать что то юзеру, то стоит вместо анонимных классов использовать свои типы для представления, как вам посоветовал AlexKrass, а каким образом вы соберете колонки для грида особого значения не имеет.

Comment: Tym, просто очень не удобно пользоваться в гриле колонки собирать если использовать анонимные типы, я думал они мне облегчат дело а оказалось подготовить data table проще. Спасибо за помощь.